# Stop WordPress compressing images? – Quality is terrible

Tags: images, thumbnails, compression

I understand WordPress creates smaller versions of the original image file.

These versions are blurry in comparison to the original which is a big issue as a photographer.

I set up this page you can see the difference https://www.jamieknop.com/test/

How can I stop WordPress compressing the images?

I tried adding the below to the functions.php file and regenerating the thumbnails but no luck.

`add_filter('jpeg_quality', function($arg){return 100;});`

Thanks,
Jamie

Answer (score 1):

You can set the width of each image sizes inside of WP > Settings > Media

Alternatively you can select the image size to be "Full image" when inserting each image into the post. This will choose the image you uploaded and not a cropped version.

Comment: The thumbnail size in WP > Settings > Media is already big.

My website theme has a gallery function so unfortunately, it's not possible to change how the images are displayed with full image.

I was able to resolve this using a plugin called WP Retina 2x :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this using a plugin called WP Retina 2x https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-retina-2x/ :)